# what is the equivalent of perf4j in .Net?

Tags: asp.net

is it stopwatch class in asp.net?

perf4j provides the following features-

Perf4J provides these features and more:

A simple stop watch mechanism for succinct timing statements.
A command line tool for parsing log files that generates aggregated statistics and performance graphs.
Easy integration with the most common logging frameworks and facades: log4j, java.util.logging, Apache Commons Logging and SLF4J.
Custom log4j appenders to generate statistics and graphs in a running application (custom java.util.logging handlers coming soon).
The ability to expose performance statistics as JMX attributes, and to send notifications when statistics exceed specified thresholds.
A servlet for exposing performance graphs in a web application.
A Profiled annotation and a set of custom aspects that allow unobstrusive timing statements when coupled with an AOP framework such as AspectJ or Spring AOP.
An extensible architecture.

Comment: Would be better if you described specifically what functionality you were looking for, so that people familiar with .NET but not with perf4j could offer advice.